# Multi platform project with flutter

Tags: flutter, web, module

How should I manage the module of mobile and web?
Should I make 3 separate modules, one for the common logic, one for the mobile and one for the web or should I put all of them inside 1 module and separate them by packages?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no. Writing another module for the web and for the common logic is not necessary.
The one thing you have to do is you need to copy the code which you have written for your mobile application and paste it in a new module and then follow the following steps, you can use your mobile application code for the purpose of the web application by simply installing the web dev package in the flutter.

You can install the package by using this command

```
flutter pub global activate webdev
```

and you have to do these changes in the pubspec.yaml file:
 1. change dependency from flutter: to flutter_web:
 2. In dev_dependency portion, change the Change flutter_test: dependency to 
    flutter_web_test:
 3. and in the same section add build_runner and build_web_compilers

So, now do a search to find "package:flutter" and change this to "package:flutter_web"
and also replace "dart:ui" to "package:flutter_web_ui/ui.dart"

After all of this, to run your application run `webdev serve`